# Right-click to translate (look up) with DeepL translator on MacOS

Tags: macos, google-translate, automator, deepl

There is an article (https://medium.com/@mrdoro/fast-translation-with-google-translator-and-mac-osx-817e32233b7a) from Lukasz Dorosz
 about using Apple Automator to integrate Google translator with macOS. I did it and it works. My question is - How can I integrate DeepL translator with macOS?

Using Automator you can integrate a Goole Translator with macOS in few steps:

> Open an Automator and create a new Service.
>   The top section set in this way:
>   From the left column you need to find and grab two functions: Run >Apple Script and Website Popup.
>   Copy and Paste this code into Apple Script window.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to "http://translate.google.com/translate_t?sl=auto&tl=ru&text=" & urldecode(input as string)
    return output
end run
on urldecode(x)
    set cmd to "'require \"cgi\"; puts CGI.escape(STDIN.read.chomp)'"
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of x & " | ruby -e " & cmd
end urldecode
```

How do I change the script to use the translator from DeepL instead of Google?

Comment: Just replacing the URL hasn't worked?

Comment: No it doesn't work :((

Comment: You may have a look into [Using Deepl API to translate text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937616/) and test also with something like https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/ru/hello.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DeepL API to translate text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937616/using-deepl-api-to-translate-text)

Comment: @Dimitri In what way didn't it work ?  I'm guessing something happened, but just not what you want. Tell us what happened and tell us what URL you used to replace the Google translate one.

Comment: @Dimitri There's now an app for Windows and Mac: https://www.deepl.com/en/app/

Answer (score 0):

You can see the DeepL link format by clicking the share button. The links look like this:

> https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Dies%20ist%20kein%20Haus.

So your script should look something like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set output to "https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/" & urldecode(input as string)
    return output
end run
on urldecode(x)
    set cmd to "'require \"cgi\"; puts CGI.escape(STDIN.read.chomp)'"
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of x & " | ruby -e " & cmd
end urldecode
```

If the text is long enough, the source language in the link should also be irrelevant, since the DeepL language recognizer determines the actual language.

The DeepL app that @tecmec recommended in his comment is probably much better than any script.